# Different coefficients: scikit-learn vs statsmodels (logistic regression)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, statsmodels

When running a logistic regression, the coefficients I get using [`statsmodels`](http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.discrete.discrete_model.Logit.html#statsmodels.discrete.discrete_model.Logit) are correct (verified them with some course material). However, I am unable to get the same coefficients with [`sklearn`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression). I've tried preprocessing the data to no avail. This is my code:

**Statsmodels:**

```
import statsmodels.api as sm

X_const = sm.add_constant(X)
model = sm.Logit(y, X_const)
results = model.fit()
print(results.summary())
```

The relevant output is:

```
                 coef    std err          z      P>|z|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
const      -0.2382      3.983     -0.060      0.952      -8.045       7.569
a           2.0349      0.837      2.430      0.015       0.393       3.676
b           0.8077      0.823      0.981      0.327      -0.806       2.421
c           1.4572      0.768      1.897      0.058      -0.049       2.963
d          -0.0522      0.063     -0.828      0.407      -0.176       0.071
e_2         0.9157      1.082      0.846      0.397      -1.205       3.037
e_3         2.0080      1.052      1.909      0.056      -0.054       4.070
```

**Scikit-learn (no preprocessing)**

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

model = LogisticRegression()
results = model.fit(X, y)
print(results.coef_)
print(results.intercept_)
```

The coefficients given are:

```
array([[ 1.29779008,  0.56524976,  0.97268593, -0.03762884,  0.33646097,
     0.98020901]])
```

And the intercept/constant given is:

```
array([ 0.0949539])
```

As you can see, regardless of which coefficient corresponds to which variable, the numbers given by `sklearn` don't match the correct ones from `statsmodels`. What am I missing? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks to a [kind soul](https://www.reddit.com/r/datascience/comments/8kne2r/different_coefficients_scikitlearn_vs_statsmodels/dz90uen) on reddit, this was solved. To get the same coefficients, one has to negate the [regularisation](https://www.kdnuggets.com/2016/06/regularization-logistic-regression.html) that `sklearn` applies to logistic regression by default:

```
model = LogisticRegression(C=1e8)
```

Where `C` according to the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html) is:

> C : float, default: 1.0
>
> Inverse of regularization strength; must be a positive float. Like in support vector machines, smaller values specify stronger regularization.

Comment: You can also turn regularization OFF as follows:  LogisticRegression(penalty = "none")

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with `statsmodel`, but could it be that the `.fit()` method of this library uses different default arguments compared to `sklearn`? To verify this, you could try to explicitly set the same corresponding arguments for each `.fit()` call, and see if you still get different results.

Answer (score 0):

you can find excellent article on this quetion in
https://blog.finxter.com/logistic-regression-scikit-learn-vs-statsmodels/