# Why am I getting wildly different results between statsmodels and sklearn's logistic regression

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, statsmodels

I know this might seem as a duplicate question, but I have done what was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50428825/different-coefficients-scikit-learn-vs-statsmodels-logistic-regression), but it didn't work. I'm working with 28 variables, some of them categorical, but I dropped the one of each variable's categories. As stated in the old question I defined:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

logit = sm.Logit(y_train, X_train)

clf = LogisticRegression(C=1e8,fit_intercept=False)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

And then, when I check my results, in `sm` my log-likelihood is -19661. In `sklearn` my log_loss is 1.9. In `sm` my coefficients range form -1.38 to 1.98. In `sklearn` they range from -0.01 to 0.02. I need my results to be more alike, so I can perform some inference on my results. What could be happening? What am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: It would help if you provide a minimal working example: include some example data and the two methods you use to provide the logistic regression.

Comment: I wanted to do that, but not easy to reproduce, because I know that with "normal" data this should work and I can't add 100+ rows of my actual data here either

Comment: Are you fitting an intercept when you use statsmodels?

Comment: Tried both ways, nothing changed

Comment: Are you classes perfectly separable? Perhaps neither solution has converged?

Comment: Didn't get an "unable to converge" error, but also I'm not sure how to check if I got results without convergence. Do you? Thanks !